# Exchange Email case sensitive?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

Ok so its more than just being case sensitive.  We have a user who is trying to email a supplier and if he is emailing the supplier directly then the supplier never gets the email.  My email filter shows that that the email has been delivered without any issues.

We had the supplier onsite today and the last time he received an email from the user but in early November so I know for a fact it worked just fine back them when emailing directly.

On the other hand when the user emails other users and the supplier is in the CC field, the email goes through to the supplier.  When sending to the supplier in the To and other recipients in the CC, the others get them but not the supplier.

The only thing I can think of is that in the Exchange server the email for the user is setup like USER@companyemail.com where everything before the @ is capital.  I have tried changing this but the Exchange server wont update with the lower case field I am typing in.

Do you guys have any ideas if there is anything that would be causing this?

Comment: Exchange server is not case sensitive, so the case of the email address is irrelevant to the problem. What do the Message Tracking and SMTP logs show?

Comment: Message Tracking doesn't show anything out the ordinary.  I cant find the SMTP logs which makes me think its not turned on or something.

Comment: If the user sent an email to the recipient then you should be able to discover the disposition of that email in the Message Tracking logs. What do you mean it doesn't show anything out of the ordinary? It should show whether or not the message was delivered to the recipient.